# Built api routes in laravel 5.x

Tags: json, rest, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm new in larevel. I want to create route in api.php. It's my code in this file

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/api', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json([
        'name' => 'Abigail',
        'state' => 'CA'
    ]);
});
```

I need to return json but when I put url mysite.com/api/api and page redirect me to mysite.com/user. How I can avoid redirect I get correct url?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that middleware syntax. Where are you getting it from?

Comment: Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});    this code generated when I create project

Comment: Tagged it with laravel 5.3 as that middleware syntax is really new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `auth` middleware and try again like:

```
Route::middleware('api')->get('/api', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json([
        'name' => 'Abigail',
        'state' => 'CA'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting redirected because you're using the `auth` middleware and are not authenticated. If the route does not need authentication just do:

```
Route::get('/api', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json([
        'name' => 'Abigail',
        'state' => 'CA'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a another example to parse direct model.

## Laravel 5.2

```
Route::middleware('api')->get('/api/users', function (Request $request) {
    return \App\Users::all();
});
```

You will get a json object for all users table data.